# AWS API / SDK to query pricing plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-reserved-instances

In AWS billing (bill file name is `accountid-aws-billing-detailed-line-items-with-resources-and-tags-year-month.csv`) there is a column "PricingPlanId", Is there any API or SDK support to query info related to the corresponding Pricing plan?

Comment: What are some example values you see in `PricingPlanId`?  It may have a different name, elsewhere.

Comment: It's a 7 digit integer(like 1422569). I assume aws maps this number to some plan internally. In case of vm ran as reserved instance it's pricing plan id is matching with the, reserved instance purchase planId.                                                                                 Example: Sign up charge for subscription: 455087981, planId: 1422569

Comment: please add more details.

Comment: okay. My use case is I want to find the true cost of a vm instance. Suppose if it was run as reserved instance for some hours then it's cost is zero for those hours(not considering partial hours, etc.). But in actual I have paid the bill for those hours as part of reserved instance. So I am trying to calculate the cost for those hours from reserved instances billing. If there are multiple matching reserved instance plans(purchased by user) then which RI plan was used for the vm is unknown. I need help in mapping the pricing plan id to Reserved instance. Thank You.

Comment: A line from my aws bill(some fields are masked) - InvoiceID(Estimated) PayerAccountId(*) ProductName(Amazon EC2) RateId(18118386) SubscriptionId(455087981) PricingPlanId(455087981) UsageType(USW2-BoxUsage:t2.micro) Operation(RunInstances) ReservedInstance(Y) ItemDescription(USD 0.0 per Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t2.micro instance-hour (or partial hour)) BlendedRate(0) BlendedCost(0) UnBlendedCost(0) ResourceId(i-xxx) - I am trying to map PricingPlanId to some reserved instance plan. Please let me know if there is any other way to get the actual cost of vm (including the reserved instance cost).

Comment: Hi, Any update on this?. Thank you.